# Routes too many redirects

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I am using the following routes however when I access `admin/login` I am getting too many redirects why?

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {

 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.admin'], function(){
    /* Admin Auth */
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
  });

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    /*Admin Dashboard Routes */

        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@getDashboard');    
    });
});
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');` is the HTML login page that should be visible to the user? If so, the middleware redirects to login page (itself) and this creates an infinite loop. Take it out of that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this middleware "auth.admin" is something that you want to check if the authenticated user is "admin",if so then if you want to open admin/login page you need to be authenticated,but because you're not authenticated you're redirecting to login page to login ,so you're getting too many redirects,hope this helps